lights no longer dimming in ceiling fan
i moved a ceiling fan from downstairs to upstairs and kept the same bulbs and everything and it’s suddenly not dimming anymore.
the old fan that was on there used to dim as well, could there be something wrong with the wiring or remote?

did you move the receiver unit as well? usualy a small black box with wires
